# How do I make fabric.js output svg including alpha color?

Tags: svg, transparency, fabricjs, alpha

I need to output the result of a fabric canvas drawing to an SVG file.

I'm using fabric.js version 1.7.6 and when I have a path drawn to a canvas with an rgba fill like `rgba(255,0,0,.15)` the resulting SVG has a fill of `rgb(0,0,0)`. Is there some setting I need to enable to make it output the alpha chanel?

In my sample code the purple circle converts to SVG properly, but the rectangle just shows up as black.

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="fabric.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="canvasHolder" style="border: 3px solid black;">
      <canvas id="canvasElement" width="400" height="400" />
    </div>

    <div id="svgHolder" style="border: 3px solid blue;">
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasElement');

    var rect = new fabric.Path('M,0,0,h,100,v,100,h,-100,z',{
        top:100,
        left:100,
        stroke: 'green',
        fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,.15)'
    });
    canvas.add(rect);

    var circ = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 30,
        top:30,
        left:30,
        stroke: 'blue',
        fill: 'purple'
    });
    canvas.add(circ);

    canvas.renderAll();

    // Make an SVG object out of the fabric canvas
    var SVG = canvas.toSVG();
   document.getElementById('svgHolder').innerHTML = SVG;
  </script>

</html>
```

Output SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.7.6</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<path d="M 0 0 h 100 v 100 h -100 z" style="stroke: rgb(0,128,0); stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(150.5 150.5) translate(-50, -50) " stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, that you should report on the [project's issue tracker](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/new). Colors are all converted to `rgb()` (`hsl`, hex, keywords)  and thus don't support alpha channel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment, this looks like a bug, that you should report on the [project's issue tracker](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/new).

Colors are all converted to rgb() (rgba, hsl, hsla, hex, keywords) and thus don't support alpha channel...

For the time being, here is an heavy workaround :

`toSVG` accepts an *reviver* function, which will receive all the svg nodes markups. From there, you can reapply the correct styles, but not so easily.

The only parameter I could find allowing us to identify which object corresponds to the svg markup we get, is the `id` one.

- So first, we will construct a dictionary, which will store our colors, by id.
- Then, we will assign the id and colors to our fabric's objects.
- Finally, in the *reviver*, we will parse our markup to convert it to an svg node, check its `id` atribute, and then change its `style.fill` and `style.stroke` properties, before returning the serialization of this modified node.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasElement');

var colors_dict = {};
// an helper function to generate and store our colors objects
function getColorId(fill, stroke) {
  var id = 'c_' + Math.random() * 10e16;
  return colors_dict[id] = {
    id: id,
    fill: fill || 'black',
    stroke: stroke || 'black' // weirdly fabric doesn't support 'none'
  }
}

// first ask for the color object of the rectangle
var rect_color = getColorId('hsla(120, 50%, 50%, .5)', 'rgba(0,0,255, .25)');
var rect = new fabric.Path('M,0,0,h,100,v,100,h,-100,z', {
  top: 60,
  left: 60,
  stroke: rect_color.stroke, // set the required stroke
  fill: rect_color.fill, // fill
  id: rect_color.id  // and most importantly, the id
});
canvas.add(rect);

var circ_color = getColorId('rgba(200, 0,200, .7)');
var circ = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 30,
  top: 30,
  left: 30,
  stroke: circ_color.stroke,
  fill: circ_color.fill,
  id: circ_color.id
});
canvas.add(circ);

canvas.renderAll();

var parser = new DOMParser();
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
function reviveColors(svg){
  // first we parse the markup we get, and extract the node we're interested in
  var svg_doc = parser.parseFromString('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svg + '</svg>', 'image/svg+xml');
  var svg_node = svg_doc.documentElement.firstElementChild;
  var id = svg_node.getAttribute('id');
  if (id && id in colors_dict) { // is this one of the colored nodes
    var col = colors_dict[id]; // get back our color object
    svg_node.style.fill = col.fill; // reapply the correct styles
    svg_node.style.stroke = col.stroke;
    // return the new markup
    return serializer.serializeToString(svg_node).replace('xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', '');
  }
  return svg;
}

// Make an SVG object out of the fabric canvas
var SVG = canvas.toSVG(null, reviveColors);
document.getElementById('svgHolder').innerHTML = SVG;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.12/fabric.js"></script>
<div id="canvasHolder" style="border: 3px solid black;">
<!-- beware canvas tag can't be self-closing -->
<canvas id="canvasElement" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="svgHolder" style="border: 3px solid blue;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around. I created a bug as requested. Linking it here in case anyone else comes across this situation. https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4004
Thanks for the great library!

Answer (score 0):

The colors are converted to RGB because svg specs wants color in CSS2 format and so rgba is unsupported.

cit: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/syndata.html#value-def-color

Fabric fulfill the transparency with the fill-opacity rull. The point is that fabric.Color color parser looks like is choking over the `.15` notation for the alpha channel.

Please use 0.15 and it will work.

i agree that fabric.Color could be fixed for this.